# Как в Intellij IDEA скомпилировать в артефакт только используемые классы?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, библиотеки

Использую в своём проекте немного функционала большой библиотеки. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы в артефакт из неё шли только те классы, которые используются мной, а не вся целая библиотека?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, у вас `Maven`-проект.

Для этих целей есть плагин `Shade`:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Он умеет автоматически выбрасывать неиспользуемые классы и зависимости.

```
<project>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                    <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

Все примеры использования:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html